# No Hilbert space can have countable Hamel basis without using Baire's Category theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have to prove that no Hilbert space can have countable Hamel basis just using the fact that any finite dimensional subspace is closed (more specifically without using Baire's theorem). I saw a paper by NAM-KIu TSING solving the same problem for Banach space. But, the proof is not much intuitive. Is it possible to give a easier proof for Hilbert space ?

Using proof by contradiction, the aim is to somehow find a Cauchy sequence and then use completeness to get a limit and show that cauchy sequence does not converge to that limit.

Thanks

Comment: Hints.  (a) Any infinite-dimensional Hilbert space has a closed subspace linearly isometric to $L^2[0,1]$.  (b) Space $L^2[0,1]$ has an uncountable linearly independent set.

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need to know that every finite-dimensional subspace is closed.  By Gram-Schmidt, given a countable Hamel basis, you can get a countable Hamel basis $\{e_n\}$ that is orthonormal.  But now if $(a_n)\in \ell^2$, the sequence of partial sums of $\sum a_n e_n$ is Cauchy and hence converges to some element $x$.  It is then easy to show that $\langle x,e_n\rangle=a_n$, and so if infinitely many $a_n$ are nonzero $x$ cannot be in the (Hamel) span of $\{e_n\}$.